# How to delete s3 life-cycle rule using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, s3-lifecycle-policy

i have n number of rules for a s3 bucket. I need to delete  one of the rule which i configured using boto3.
but I am not finding the command for that. if I use
response = s3.bucket_lifecycle.delete() or
response = s3.delete_bucket_lifecycle(Bucket='examplebucket',)

how it will find a particular rule which i need to delete ?

Comment: After 3 years, there is still no API to do this. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: For a solution that works, see: [How can a single S3 Lifecycle rule be deleted with boto3 SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77841065/174777)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `boto3.resource` to do this. See [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#bucketlifecycle).

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket_lifecycles = s3.BucketLifecycle('bucket_name').rules

# pick a lifecycle and delete
for bucket_lifecycle in bucket_lifecycles:
    if bucket_lifecycle['ID'] == 'something':
        bucket_lifecycle.delete()
```

Comment: This does not work. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround mentioned on this stackoverflow question [how-can-a-single-s3-lifecycle-rule-be-deleted-with-boto3-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77838433/how-can-a-single-s3-lifecycle-rule-be-deleted-with-boto3-sdk)

```
bucket_lifecycles = s3_resource.BucketLifecycleConfiguration(bucket).rules
    
    for bucket_lifecycle in bucket_lifecycles:
        if bucket_lifecycle['ID'] == lifecycle_id:
            bucket_lifecycles.remove(bucket_lifecycle)                
            break
    
    s3_client.put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration(
        Bucket=bucket,
        LifecycleConfiguration={
            'Rules':bucket_lifecycles
        }
    )
```