# How can a single S3 Lifecycle rule be deleted with boto3 SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

There is only the API for deleting all lifecycle rules but no API for deleting a single rule. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/delete_bucket_lifecycle.html

There is a similar question on stackoverflow, which has a non-working answer.
[How to delete s3 life-cycle rule using boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63510950/how-to-delete-s3-life-cycle-rule-using-boto3)

I can't believe that Amazon does not provide an API to do this while the same is possible on S3 console.

Comment: The [put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration - Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration.html) page says: _"if you want to retain any configuration details, they must be included in the new lifecycle configuration."_ So, you can't delete an individual rule, but you can take the existing definition, remove the rule, then use `put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration()` to replace the existing configuration.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks for the idea. It worked. You should put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @JohnRotenstein comment, this is the way to delete an individual lifecycle rule from S3.

```
bucket_lifecycles = s3_resource.BucketLifecycleConfiguration(bucket).rules

for bucket_lifecycle in bucket_lifecycles:
    if bucket_lifecycle['ID'] == lifecycle_id:
        bucket_lifecycles.remove(bucket_lifecycle)                
        break

s3_client.put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration(
    Bucket=bucket,
    LifecycleConfiguration={
        'Rules':bucket_lifecycles
    }
)
```